# Move Data from one entity to another entity

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have 2 entities Documents(Id,Number,Content,Date_Added) and Adocuments(archives of documents)(Ida,Number,Content,Date_Added) and I want to **move** the Documents (for example) from march in my archive entity. My tables have the same fields.

Select part

```
WPF_TestEntities WPFModel;
DateTime init_per = new DateTime(2012, 03, 01);
DateTime fina_per = new DateTime(2012, 03, 31);
var qry = from d in WPFModel.Document // qry - documents form march
          where d.Date_Added >= init_per &&  d.Date_Added <= fina_per
          select d;
```

Insert part

```
//WPFModel.Adocument.Insert/Add(qry);
```

After that I can delete the march documents from the Document entity.

How can I move the data(qry) from Documents to Adocuments? (will there be any problems with the uniqueness of my Id ?)

Comment: Sorry it's not really clear what is your question.

Comment: I think that there are 3 stages (the select, the insert and the delete)

Comment: I guess this depends on the design of the current application. If you use archive table solely as a "back-up location", without any fancy mirroring, then you shouldn't have any problems with ids on select-insert-delete. Try drawing this on a paper, what happens when. Once you have a clear picture try running some integration tests, covering happy paths (select-insert-delete), later you can check corner cases (such as removed entry is being updated). You may also need to wrap this into batched transactions (say you do this in small chunks of N documents).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
 WPF_TestEntities WPFModel;
 DateTime init_per = new DateTime(2012, 03, 01);
 DateTime fina_per = new DateTime(2012, 03, 31);
 var qry = from d in WPFModel.Document // qry - documents form march
      where d.Date_Added >= init_per &&  d.Date_Added <= fina_per
      select d;

 foreach (Document doc in qryluna)
     {
      Adocument newadoc = new Adocument();
      newadoc.IdA = doc.Id;
      newadoc.Nr_intern = doc.Nr_intern;
      newadoc.Obiect = doc.Obiect;
      newadoc.Data_Added = doc.Data_Added ;
      WPFModel.Adocument.AddObject(newadoc);
      WPFModel.Document.DeleteObject(doc);
  }
  WPFModel.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I've moved SaveChanges outside of the foreach

Answer (score 0):

you can do trying downcasting the element result from query, if it will not run you should take each element and copy to a new bject, than you can save it in hystory table.
The id could be a problem, because if you settled the id as autoincrement (identity on sql server) of course the db will try to release a new id, instead your old one.
The most secure task that you should do is to questy the first entity, take each values and fill a new hystorical entity (related to the hystory table) and save it.
I guess that you could have the second table (Adocuments) with those fields:

- id (your table identity id)
- ida (your id copied from  Documents table, to really maintain the history)
- number
- content
- date_added

I hope this is useful for you :)